# Windows escape sequence issue with file path in java

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io, io

I need to use windows file path to do some operation on files but i am getting invalid escape sequence error.

```
File f = new File("C:\test");
```

the system accepts only " \\ " or  "/" but if I copy file path from windows it is with "\".
how can i solve this issue

Comment: Why not simply find and replace every \ with \\ ?

Comment: problem is where should i store  file path with "\" as i cannot use String as it gives the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Use File.separator in place of "".

```
File f = new File("C:"+File.separator+"test");
```

File.separator returns "" and it is not treated as an **escape** character.

If your file `test.txt` is saved in folder D:/MyFloder/MyPrograms you can do something like this

```
File f = new File("D:"+File.seperator+"MyFloder"+File.separator+"MyPrograms"+File.separator+"test.txt");
```

**EDIT**

You don't need to worry about OS

For Unix : `File.separator = /`

For Windows : `File.separator = \`

Comment: if i have path like this "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.200.v20130514-1256\META-INF" is it make sense to use your logic

Comment: This is still overly complicated -- just use `/` and the JVM will sort it out.

Answer (score 3):

`\` is the escape character in Java Strings. Use `\\` instead.

`"C:\\test"` resolves to the String `C:\test`

Comment: How can i replace escape character I dont want to replace manually. i.e. everytime I copy path from windows and then replace it.

Comment: @user2614607 you can use String's `replaceAll()` method to do that for you.

Comment: No, you can't use replaceAll to do that. You have to replace it yourself, or use your IDE to help - any good IDE will have a "replace text in selection" function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\\` or `/` but `/` is better because it is OS-independent.

Replace the single backslash in the path with a double backslash or a single forward slash to solve your issue.

Internally, Java will convert it to the file seperator of the OS

Comment: IMHO this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

`File f = new File("C:\\test");` is correct.

You are not creating a File with the path "C:\\test" here. You are creating a File with the path "C:\test". The \\-to-\ conversion happens when you compile the program - by the time your program is running, the double backslashes are gone.

The same for String - `String s = "C:\\test";` does not create a string with two backslashes, only one.

You can think of it this way: the string does not actually have two backslashes, but you have to write it that way to put it in your code.

You might be wondering why that is - it's because backslashes are used to insert special characters in strings. When you type `\t` in a string it inserts a tab, for example. If you want to insert a backslash, then t, you type `\\t`.

Comment: This will work, but it's a lot simple to just use forward slashes and allow the JVM to do the conversion when needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use '/' (as in Linux) in paths since Windows XP, so forget about \

Answer (score -2):

Use `java.nio.file.Path` instead of `java.io`, you'll not have problem with escape sequence character :

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
    Path path = Paths.get("C:\test");
```

Comment: This is very (!) wrong. In Java source code `\` has to be replaced by `\\` since ´\´ is the escape code used for special characters. This has in no way anything to do with "io" or "nio".