# file handling in java error escape character

Tags: java, netbeans

### trying to register a new user and the login part is done only the registering im having issues. it says illegal escape character but run successfully

```
package register;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Register {

   public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          try{
              File  newUser = new File ("C:\Users\Rohani\Desktop\Filehandling\newUser.txt"); //theres an error saying illegal escape char
              if (newUser.createNewFile()){
                  System.out.println("User created: " + newUser.getName());
              }else{
                  System.out.println("User already exist.");
              }
          } catch(IOException e ){
              System.out.println("An error has occured.");
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\` char is used for escaping in Java Strings.

You can use `\\` instead of `\` or use `/`.

Duplicate of:

[Windows escape sequence issue with file path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324962/windows-escape-sequence-issue-with-file-path-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslashes in your path. instead of writing `\` replace them with `\\`