# FileNotFound Exception in Java when the file already exists

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to open an Excel file whose complete path is stored in a String *filePath*. The content of *filePath* is *C:/fullpath/Names.xlsx*. I am trying the following code:

```
String filePath = jobject.get(Constants.SOURCE_PATH).toString();
File file = new File(filePath);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

It is throwing me the following error at the last statement.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\fullpath\Names.xlsx" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Also, the file is not saved in the working directory. Not sure what is wrong here. Could some Java experts please look into it?

Thanks

Comment: The exception is saying the file does not exist - if I use your code against an existing file I don't get an exception. So it is likely that the file really doesn't exist (maybe a typo?).

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with escaping [Windows escape sequence issue with file path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324962/windows-escape-sequence-issue-with-file-path-in-java)?

Comment: @assylias The file does exist.

Comment: @Swap2019: I assume there isn't a directory called `fullpath` in the root directory of your `C:` drive, right? When the JVM tells you the file doesn't exist it is almost always correct. Maybe showing us the *actual* error message with path and a screenshot of explorer with that file showing might help? A common error is the "hide common file extensions" setting in Explorer.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
String filePath = Paths.get(Constants.SOURCE_PATH).toString();
File file = new File(filePath);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Constants.java

```
// or static final String SOURCE_PATH = "D:/workspace/files/names.xlsx";
static final String SOURCE_PATH = "D:\\workspace\\files\\names.xlsx";
```

If I deliberately make the file name wrong, I get the same error as yours.

Your file might not really exist.